# Installing just in time debugging

Tags: sql, excel, visual-studio, debugging, crash

I pull data for my department each morning into a SQL Query Connected Excel document, I have dozens of these reports and all but one work 100% of the time. The other, crashes on saving the document roughly 66% of the time. When I attempt to debug it and see why I get this message: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O5uv.png

I then followed the Microsoft documentation on installing the debugger:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2019#disable-just-in-time-debugging-from-the-windows-registry

However, when I open the options tab in visual studios I don't see that option:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEWNO.png

I installed the free community version for reference. I'd love any help that could be offered!